# time.sleep(x) not working as it should?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, sleep

Okay, so I'm making a small programme for fun and I'd like to create a refresh button that allows the user to control how regularly the data is collected and shown. I decided to use the time.sleep(x) x being what the raw_input was. But it doesn't seem to be working as it should. It pauses the full script then does everything.

eg:

```
import time

print "This now"
time.sleep(x)
print "and this after x amount of  seconds"
```

So should print the first part then the second after x amount of seconds.

But instead it prints all of it at once after x amount of seconds.

When I use a if statement after it seems to wait an extra x amount seconds for printing whatever's in the if statement.

This really messes up my data when put in anything higher than 0 its old data by x amount. 
For example, if I put in 60 it would be a whole minute old data (not live). Leaving it at 0 just spams the console with too much though making it impossible to read.

Any idea why and how to fix my problem?

Comment: Your stdout is buffered -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because of output buffering. You should turn it off. Refer to this post:
[Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)